# How to install ROS on Windows?

Tags: ros, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hai

i want to build a robot which autonomously navigates by using ROS.First I want to download ROS into my computer and want to learn how to navigate to a point.I have windows 7 in my pc.

can u tell me how to do it??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41347/how-to-install-ros-on-windows?/) by [vamshi krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/3029/vamshi-krishna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vamshi krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/3029/vamshi-krishna/) on 2012-08-16**:
Thank u guys....i will go wid ubuntu den....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently Windows support is only experimental. I would recommend you to install an Ubuntu Linux and get familiar with the Ubuntu Package Manager that is used to manage software. Once you have done that, you can proceed to the ROS installation instructions for Ubuntu:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2012-08-14**:
I second this suggestion - If you're just getting started with ROS, you don't want the headache of using an unsupported operating system. You'll want to set up your machine as a dual boot, following the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot. It's surprisingly painless.

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-08-14**:
That's definitely a good idea, thanks for mentioning!

**Comment by [donald](https://answers.ros.org/users/24812/donald/) on 2016-06-01**:
And I guess once you have discovered the beauty of Linux, you will get rid of your Windows partition ;-)

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-19**:
After 4 years, are we still in experimental stage?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-07-11**:
@pallavbakshi here is the best option today, from my understanding ROS Lunar works: http://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows, http://answers.ros.org/question/238646/installing-ros-on-ubuntu-bash-in-windows-10/

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-08-07**:
I have updated the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-08-07**:
thanks @Victor

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of now, ROS only has experimental Windows support. You can find out more here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3